# WebDAV + davfs -- error copying large files

Tags: windows, logs, apache-httpd, webdav, davfs2

I am using Apache on server, with WebDAV.
On client Linux, I have davfs2 mounted folder. When I try to access small file, everything works fine. When I try to access image file size of 2Gb, I am getting `Input/output error`. My guess is that there is some limitation on Apache/WebDAV side. In httpd.conf I have `LogLevel debug`, but still logs doesn't show much about this error. Question is: how to enable WebDAV detailed logs and what are default size limitations in WebDAV for upload and download?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`davfs` manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/mount.davfs.8.html):

> `mount.davfs` needs to hold a local copy of all open files in the cache directory. Please make sure that enough local disk space is available.

So you should check that there is enough space to the default cache dirs like:

- `~/.davfs2/cache` for user mounts
- `/var/cache/davfs2` for system-wide mounts

You have to check which is the largest file and ensure that fits in the filesystems where the mentioned directories are mounted on.

You can use a `df -h /var/cache/davfs2` to easy know how much space left is on the specific filesystem associated to a directory.